# How to write integration tests for pasting content

Tags: javascript

I have created an online editor, and I have written a complete suite of tests for the editor.

Now, I'd like to write an integration test for pasting content using various shortcuts (ctrl+v, ctrl+shift+v, shift+ins). I would like my test to look something like this:

```
copyText("test");
setEditorContent("value:");
simulateKey("Ctrl+V");
expectContent("value:test");
```

I would like to run the tests either in broswer or in jest using jsdom.

Now, is it possible to write this test? Because I know that broswers block client code from pasting stuff from clipboard, as a security meassure - you can only read clipboard in a "paste" event, and you can't simulate the paste event (that's done to forbid websites from lurking into your clipboard).

So is there a way to automate this test? I would hate to leave this part untested, but I also don't want to manually click RPM->Paste, in order to test that.